# How I can monitor all Internet requests?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to monitor all requested URLs using the .NET framework classes?

Comment: i want to log all requested URLs into database ????

Comment: @MSalters has an excellent point. It is not clear whether you want to log *incoming* requests to a server, or all *outgoing* traffic from a machine. The "best" answer will be very different depending on your scenario.

Comment: i want to log all outgoing traffic from a machine , is there any useful to log all incoming ????

Comment: That's clientside (webbrowser). If you run a webserver (website), as Claudio Redi assumed, you'd certainly want to log incoming requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a HttpModule. It will intercept ALL requests and you could do any monitoring there.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719858%28VS.71%29.aspx) you have an example about how to implement an HttpModule

More info about this on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) msnd article

Another option is to use the global.asax. Log what you need on `Application_BeginRequest`

Comment: Note that this answer is serverside and logs incoming requests.

Comment: And it's an answer only for ASP.Net server.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Core/) to integrate Fiddler capabilities into your application.

Comment: That's HTTP only, and then only for browsers that use Fiddler as a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com), for example.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the IIS logs of your web server.  See the following link to determine where they are: http://portal.smartertools.com/KB/a154/where-are-my-iis-log-files-stored.aspx